# How to make emacs shell execute init file automatically?

Tags: emacs, bash

My bash init script (~/.profile) contains important initializations, but whenever I use shell-command or compile in emacs, that init file is not read, and without those initialization my bash commands in emacs will fail :( How do I force emacs to execute my init file for the shell that it's using for shell-command?

Clarification: I'm not talking about M-x shell, which reads my init file just fine when I symlinked .profile to .emacs_bash.

Answer (score 22):

Move your initialization routines into your `~/.bashrc` file

Then add the line

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

into your `~/.bash_profile` file. See the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for a detailed explanation of which startup files get loaded when. The key is the difference between an *interactive* and *non-interactive* shell, as well as the difference between a *login* and a *non-login* shell.

In general, `.bash_profile` is run when logging into the system using a shell while `.bashrc` is run when starting a new shell (The OS X Terminal application is an exception to this rule as it runs `.bash_profile` for each new terminal instance). For more info in article form, [look here.](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)

Comment: I symlinked my .profile to both .bashrc and .bash_profile. Does not seem to work still. Does emacs start an interactive or non-interactive shell? I also tried adding --login to the explicit-bash-args, and still no luck.

Comment: Ahh, now I can love my Emacs shell again! Thank you! :D

Comment: @DanFilimon this was the complete solution to my problem as well! :) Emacs shell works with nvm now!

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Mac, shell-command did not execute .bashrc, nor .bash_profile, I googled a solution to have my PATH problem fixed.

put this in your .emacs:
(setenv "PATH" (shell-command-to-string "source ~/.bashrc; echo -n $PATH"))

more detail, see: [How to make emacs to run my ~/.bash_profile](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-09/msg00616.html)

Answer (score 2):

Digging through the elisp source; seems like the shell-command in emacs just executes bash -c "command" in my case. Solution is to start emacs (emacs &) in a shell where my .profile is already executed (instead of starting emacs from the GUI menus of my windows manager).

Comment: Thanks, polyglot, starting emacs from a terminal worked for me as well.